# I want to deploy token vesting contract .Is storing tokens on smart contract secured?

Tags: solidity

I am tring to deploy Vesting Contract for my token . So token will be released according to time.But I am not sure about storing all token in vesting contract.Is it secured ? .Or their is another way of doing it.

Comment: It depends on the vesting contract security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can store any amount of token on that vesting smart contract. The security part really depends on your contract logic.
There are also other ways to acheive this. Like you can use any other smart contract with this purpose of storing tokens. Depending on your requirement, you can also keep reward distribution logic on this contract as well.